# disabled="true" appears in text box when php/sql query returns null

Tags: php, mysql

I want to disable textbutton so that it is not editable. The data in the textbutton comes from a sql query. Disable works fine when the query returns a value. However, when there is no value, it shows "disabled="true"" instead of just being greyed-out.

Here's my code:

```
<?php

$con=mysqli_connect("hostname","username","password","database");
 // Check connection
 if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
 echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
}

$IMEI = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['IMEI']);

$result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM mobile
WHERE IMEI LIKE '$IMEI%'");

while($data = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
echo "<input type='text' value=".$data['IMEI']." disabled='true'>";
echo "<input type='text' value=".$data['SecIMEI']." disabled='true'>";
echo "<input type='text' value=".$data['Brand']." disabled='true'>";
echo "<input type='text' value=".$data['Model']." disabled='true'>";
echo "<input type='text' value=".$data['Color']." disabled='true'>";
echo "<input type='text' value=".$data['Remarks']." disabled='true'>";
}
?>

<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Untitled Document</title>
</head>

<body>
<fieldset><legend>Search Mobile</legend> <br>
<form method="post">
 IMEI: <input type="text" name="IMEI"> </pre><input type="submit" action="searchmob2.php">
</form>
</fieldset>


</body>
</html>
```

Also, how can I hide the php part when the page is loaded?

Comment: You need to add ' around your value aswell. Like this for example: value='".$data['IMEI']."'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're missing quotes around your value attribute.  Change:

```
echo "<input type='text' value=".$data['IMEI']." disabled='true'>";
```

to:

```
echo "<input type='text' value='".$data['IMEI']."' disabled='true'>";
```

Also, you should loop through the while loop in the body of the page - at the moment it's going to echo it before the HTML header.

Answer (score 0):

To "hide" the php part when the page is loaded, you'd simply check if the page was loaded with a post param - like this:

```
<?php
if( isset($_POST['IMEI']) ) {
  ... 
}
```

Also, check your quotes:

```
...
echo "<input type='text' value='".$data['IMEI']."' disabled='true'>";
...
```

Comment: Thanks! This solved the php "hide" part. Thanks a lot!